# WinRT MVVM Light Sample Project

Tags: windows-8, mvvm-light, windows-runtime

If anyone starts developing Windows 8 metro applications using MVVM Light please help me to create a Windows 8 (WinRT) project template. I get bored by using Microsoft ‘s  Layoutaware page(Base class). I just need to structure the class with the help of MVVM Light. If any one did this please help me or provide some links to start developing Windows 8 Metro application using MVVM Light.

The major areas where i am facing  issues are:

1. Navigation (Forward and Backward)
2. State Handling (Tombstoning in windows 8)
3. Navigation after the app launches form termination state etc.
4. Handling WebService [ Post using http client ]

Comment: You asked at least 4 questions.  You should break it up into four posts so your questions can be answered individually.

Comment: There is no documentation for using MVVM Light with Win RT anywhere on the web. I applaud you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an (older) example of using MVVM Light with windows 8 found [here](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2012/02/19/impressions-slides-and-code-from-techdays-belgium-and-netherlands.aspx).  There are also templates and Samples as part of the MVVM Light source found [here](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/b922e8ccf674).

Edit:
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj651572.aspx) is an msdn example using MVVM Light.

Comment: The above sample are not much useful. It would be great if we have any sample app developed with MVVM Light, which demonstrates all the aspect of ideal Windows Store App. I have seen [Itinerary Hunter](https://github.com/stevenh77/ItineraryHunter-Win8) sample app which is developed with [Kona](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/discussions/konaguidance.codeplex.com), Windows 8 equivalent of PRISM.

Comment: @Xyroid That would be nice, but not really feasible.  The "ideal" Windows Store App is partly a result of what you're trying to make, what libraries have been developed and what the community has developed.  Those last two parts make a perfect demo app pretty much impossible.

Comment: ideal means the basic things like navigation, contracts, event handling, binding, etc

Answer (score 0):

What about [this](https://staging.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight/4.1.23)

But I did not try it. I'm using Portable class library (with targets Windows 8.1 and .NET x.xx) and this library is referenced to WinRT project. MvvmLight for PCL you can find on [this link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.MvvmLightLibs/)

Problem is, that you can't access Local files and Local settings but you can inject it from Presentation project to Portable class library at the start.

This solution has a lot of advantages and one of the is : easiest unit testing.

For more info look this stack overflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123999/mvvmlight-in-portable-class-library-how-to-do-unit-testing)