# Implementing State handling in windows 8 using MVVM Light

Tags: windows-8, mvvm-light, windows-runtime

How i can implement state handling (running / resume / Terminate states ) using mvvm light. The major issue i a facing is with Navigation. I am totally uncontrolled with the navigation stack. How i can effectively manage this with MVVM Light.

Comment: How do you connect your view models to your views? You could create a base view model class extended by all your page view models that exposes virtual methods called when application state changes so that your view models can respond to these events.

Comment: That I did. But my issue is that, when my app falls to terminate state, all my state information are losing. In the usual case VS12 are using a  class know as “SuspensionManager” for handling this and for default navigation. My doubt is how can i use the behavior of SuspensionManager class to implement a mvvmlight based structure. The major issue is with restoring the active frame and navigation stack..

Comment: @Filip : You can find my implementation here :https://www.dropbox.com/sh/px60d6q2snimbv3/qJ0Zw6r2Zx

Comment: @Flip :Plenty of them are facing similar issues 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632285/winrt-mvvm-light-sample-project
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811138/state-handling-in-windows-8-using-mvvmlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in the open source [Okra App Framework](http://okra.codeplex.com) that is freely available on CodePlex and NuGet (disclaimer: I am the lead developer on this project). This has been designed from the ground up for Windows 8 applications, in particular those that use the MVVM pattern (and you can still use the MVVM Light base classes to define your view-models).

Of particular interest it includes,

- A navigation manager that understands the Windows 8 navigation model
- A navigation stack that can automatically persist its state upon application termination
- A mechanism for view-models to persist their own state (via a simple interface)
- Automatic view and view-model construction and wiring up (by default using MEF attributes)

Comment: Hi, Its look pretty promising ?? Can I reuse your code in my project template. Is there any copyright issues? All your implantation looks great. The only one missing I found is the lack of support for "Event aggregation function. If you include that too. I am sure its going to be a blaster. Is possible provide some sample implementation apps. Then it would help a lot for starters like me.

Comment: @StezPet : Yes. The Okra App Framework is released under the Ms-PL license which means you can use the code however you want (within reason!). Regarding event aggregation, I am avoiding this at the moment as Okra is designed to work well alongside an MVVM framework rather than replace entirely (you can always use MVVM light for this purpose). For sample code check out one of the earlier source code commits - I removed a sample app from the main download a bit back and am aiming to release this separately in future (and also aiming to overhaul the docs).

Answer (score 4):

Start a new project using either the GridView or SplitView templates and take a look at **SuspensionManager.cs** in the **Common** folder. It has a method called RegisterFrame which, when called, starts tracking all of the navigation events from the frame and attempts to save off and restore state when the application suspends and resumes.

The applications main frame is registered with the SuspensionManager in App.OnLaunched (App.xaml.cs) and Saving is done in App.OnSuspending.

Finally, take a look at **LayoutAwarePage.cs**, also in the **Common** folder. You can inherit from LayoutAwarePage to get Portrait and Snapped design time support. It also attempts to handle navigation state caching by leveraging the SuspensionManager. So, no matter whether your page is navigated to from another page or as part of a resume, the virtual method **LoadState** is called with the correct data.

Obviously this pattern is managing  navigation state  directly in the page itself, but you could tweak this pattern to create a sort of "SuspensionService" that your ViewModels could leverage in the same way.

Comment: can you help me based on my implementation , you can find my code here : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/px60d6q2snimbv3/qJ0Zw6r2Zx

Comment: I would just assume that navigation state is part of the view in the MVVM stack and then it does not really matter if you are using MVVM Light since you are just restoring the state of the view. Your navigation service is dependent on the view anyway.

You could add methods on your base view model class that will be called by your base page class when navigation events occur, so the view models know when to save/restore their state.

Also, you could use the Messenger class to publish state change events when they occur and subscribe to these in the view models so they can respond appropriately

Comment: @Flip : Can you suggest some samples or documents to refer. I am new to this world and feel struggle to get adapted to this new world.  If u suggest some code samples it would be grateful for me to start with.  Thanks for the response. And hop u will help me further to achieve my goal.stz

Comment: Hi Jared : Instead of dialogues provide some samples.

Comment: @Flip : Hi Flip, I think you had tried this before. Can you paste some code snippets, then it would be helpful for us. I too had similar issues in my project .  Expecting a positive replay.

Comment: Sorry, I have not touched state management APIs in WinRT yet. I can look into it, but it might take a couple of days/weeks before I get there.

Comment: I didn't have any code because I was talking about a pattern and not an implementation. If I was going to build it, I'd probably start by leveraging SuspensionManager.cs exactly as it is. SuspensionManager already exposes a static property called SessionState that can be accessed from anywhere in the application. This is a dictionary of named values that get persisted and restored. If you need more than that (like settings per ViewModel) try setting a Dictionary<String, Object> as one name in the SessionState property. Or, change the SessionStateForFrame method to work with views instead.